# Combinatorics: Prove that $x, y, z$ exist such that $\frac {1}{2} \leq \frac {x^2}{yz} \leq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose we have a subset of $2n-1$ numbers from the set ${1, 2, 3, ..., 2^n-2}$. Prove that there exits $x, y, z$ such that $\frac {1}{2} \leq \frac {x^2}{yz} \leq 2$

I'm fairly new to this topic, and i honestly have no idea how to prove this. Any hint on how can i start the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide the numbers into 123, 4567, 8 to 15, 16 to 31, etc and apply pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: If the numbers don't have to be distinct, this is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.- Consider the rational function $f(X)=\dfrac{(X-2)^2}{(X-3)(X-4)}$.

It is easy to prove that $$\begin{cases}f(X)\le2\text{ when } X\gt7\\f(X)\ge\dfrac12\text{ when } X\gt5\end{cases}$$ 
Making now $X=2^x$ the inequalities above prove that for $n\ge3$ (*in which cas*e $X\ge8$) a solution is given by
$$x=2^n-2\\y=2^n-3\\z=2^n-4$$ It remains to solve the values  $n=1$ and $n=2$ in which cases $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1),(1,1,2)$ are trivial solutions.